# How do I create a Firebase user from C#?

Tags: c#, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase, and I want to be able to create a user, get his ID, and then create his profile data.

I can do this using Google.Cloud.Firestore, just the way we do it in Android. However, I want to do this from a C# web application.

I have not been able to find anything that creates an auth user that is callable from C#. How can I do this?

There's this FirebaseUI Widget in javascript which really gives a lot's of auth options out of the box (Google, phone, email/password, etc.), but I need to use my own interface (i.e., the interface required by my client).

Comment: https://www.ashishvishwakarma.com/creating-c-sharp-wrapper-over-firebase-api-for-basic-crud/

Comment: Couldn't find anything on auth signup

Answer (score 1):

There is no SDK for accessing Firebase Authentication from C#/ASP.NET web application.

But there is a [REST API for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/) that you can call from any platform that can make HTTPS calls, and which has a method to [create a user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-create-email-password).

---

A quick search also lead me to this third-party [library by Step Up Labs](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet), but I have no experience with it.

Comment: This one from Step Up Labs is for authenticating into realtime db. No user creation. Will look into the Rest API and let u know, thank u Frank.

Comment: Under [Supported scenarios](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet#supported-scenarios) it lists "Create new user with email + password". This part of the library implementation also seem promising: https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet/blob/a2be7f1a830a3355c7751bd5e93a3a271613bcf3/src/Firebase.Auth/FirebaseAuthProvider.cs#L141

Comment: Well the Rest API has everything I'm not looking for. I'm looking for signup with phone number. And all I can find for this kind of signup is thru the aforementioned javascript widget, which excludes using my own ui.

Comment: Yes, Step up labs, has the email/pwd signup. But I'm looking for phone signup (sigh)